# In Red vs Blue, why was Agent Tex given an AI?

Tags: red-vs.-blue

I'm rewatching the series because I love the show. As it fleshes out the Freelancer arc, it sets backgrounds for many of the characters and it reveals more about their nature.

It's shown that Agent Texas was just a robot and imbued with the Beta AI. The Beta emerged alongside the Alpha* but was never experimented upon, unlike the Alpha. It makes sense because the Director projected the Beta as Allison. He could torture himself (Alpha) but he wouldn't stand to have anything remotely tied to Allison to be mutilated.

Connie (CT) figured it out and eventually Carolina did too.

One fundamental rule with AI fragments was that each was forbidden from communicating directly with one another. In that case, why was Agent Texas--an AI--given Omega? It's not likely she would have needed it for augmentation as she already possesses the same enhancing ability.

It flies directly in the face of what Dr. Leonard strictly enforced as a rule.

Comment: hmm....conflicted as to whether RvB is on-topic in the spirit of SF&F - can't put my finger on it but not invested enough to vote to close or anything like that - just wondering if anyone else felt odd about it as well

Comment: @NKCampbell [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_vs._Blue) describes it as science fiction parody series. Parody or not, it's still science fiction. If [Calvin and Hobbes](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10795/70236) is on topic, so is this.

Comment: @NKCampbell I feel that if fanfic is on topic, RvB is on topic.

Comment: RvB is definitely Sci-Fi.

Answer (score 1):

1. It would have been a bit weird if she *didn't* have one. She thinks so quickly and fights so much better than any human ever could, if she didn't have an AI as an easy explanation the others would very quickly start to wonder why she was so capable.
2. It was partly a ploy by The Director. Omega (aka O'Malley) represented the Alpha's rage and was implanted within Tex to make her more aggressive and dangerous, not to help her with her abilities.
3. After some time working with Omega, Tex actually starts to take him out of her head and goes for longer and longer periods of time without using him. This is part of the reason why he goes rogue and starts possessing other people after she gets to Blood Gulch.

Comment: Good answer but I have some reservations on these points: 1) Carolina was able to rival Tex and could perform superhuman feats of speed and strength without the assistance of an AI. It could be plausibly acceptable that Tex wouldn't need one. 2) Placing an aggressive AI would put Tex in more danger which seems counter to his intention. Refer to the fight with Carolina after she possessed Eta and Iota. 3) Where did you get the reasoning as to why O'Malley started to jump from host to host? I don't recall hearing why he did that and it'd be interesting to see the source.

Comment: Also, I wanted to levy another question against your second point: when Carolina fought with Tex after she was implanted with Eta and Iota, the Director called out the name Allison to which each AI fragment reacted rather violently. Considering the nature of Agent Texas and the Beta AI, I wonder why Tex (and O'Malley) wasn't affected. Seemed rather odd, no?

Comment: 1) The whole point of Season 10 is that Carolina isn't able to reach Tex's level. 2) It might seem contradictory, but that's what he did. 3) I got things a bit backwards. There's actually a deleted scene where Omega possesses somebody else (A guard named "O'Malley") and the reason Tex starts taking him out her head is because he starts possessing people.

Comment: And 4) I'm not really sure, seems like that's a different question you might have to ask.